# Not Auto launching app when I run thru android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I right click my project-> Run -> All Tests

Its Building and Installing in my Devices.

But app is not automatically launching like in eclipse.

It seems like I installed it through `adb install` in terminal. Need to manually open each time I installed.

Comment: tests are not for normal run, please watch some intellij android tutorials on youtube

Comment: eclipse? What year is it??

Comment: I have been running into this issue with android 6.x devices with android studio 4.1 version. I have to run the app 2x or more to get it to auto launch the app. It does install the app, but does not launch the app. Only happening on the my android 6.x devices though. Android 7.x+ all launch fine.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It is because you are running it as a 'test' and not as an 'Android Application'.

1. Open the "Edit Configurations" pane and click the '+' button.
2. Select the option to create a new 'Android Application' and then select the correct module.
3. Apply, and you can then delete the test configuration you were using before if you wish.

Then every time you run, make sure you are running as an Android Application and not a test, and it will auto-launch on install.

Answer (score 44):

In Android Studio you must go to Run -> Edit configurations -> select Launch default Activity

Comment: Why isn't this enabled by default, just like previous studio versions? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @iCantC Because the project was probably created with no activies at all, so it defaults to Nothing.

Answer (score 31):

File > Invalidate Caches / Restart fixes the problem.

Comment: Worked for me when the run configuration was already set to launch the app but seemingly stopped for no apparent reason (on Pixel 5a physical phone).

Answer (score 31):

I had the same issue, steps that helped me :

- go to run -> modify run configurations -> on the bottom there is Launch Options.
- as you can see Launch: Nothing [image]
- change from [Nothing] to [Default Activity]
  [image]
- Hit apply and then ok, now it should work.
  [image]

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer to activities not launching by default under Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1

Answer (score 12):

In my case, setting the `android:exported` attribute in `AndroidManifest.xml` to `false` for my Launcher activity was causing the issue. Setting it to `true` fixed the issue, but what if I don't want to set it to true?

Maybe this is an issue with Android Studio, the current version I'm using is: `Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 2`

Starting with Android 12 you need to explicitly declare the android:exported attribute:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12

Comment: My Problem Fixed :-)

Answer (score 2):

Updating Android Studio to the latest version solved the problem in my case.

Comment: this is funny because the latest update causes the issue for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Disabling Instant run worked for me. Don't know the reason behind it though.

To disable Instant run (on Android Studio 2.3) navigate to File >> Settings >> Build, Execution, Deployment >> Uncheck Instant Run.

Comment: Not sure why, but this fixed my problem on IntelliJ CE

Answer (score 2):

In my case the package name was different in `build.gradle` and `Launcher Activity`

Making the package name in build.gradle same as that of Launcher Activity solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. first step

[image]

And

2. second step

[image]

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Open your MainActivity.
- Right button of the mouse and select 'Run MainActivity'

Answer (score 1):

In my case in Edit Confirgurations There was no launch activity selected so i changed the option from Nothing to Default Activity

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall then Reinstall app in your phone
2. invalidate caches
3. Restart Android studio
4. Enable online gradle build
5. Sync project
6. Check which activity is launcher activity then check the oncreate() method of that activity
7. Use USB for the testing app instead of ADB WIFI, after resolving issues use ADB wifi again.
8. Try enabling multidex in gradle
9. package name may be different in build.gradle and Launcher Activity (once happened to me)
10. On the left to left of run button, choose the "app" from the list in android studio
11. Sometimes when we create XML files then they do not connect with their activities so you need to invalidate cahes and restart android studio

EDIT: One more thing I added abmob using firebase in android studio but forgot to add the publication id from admob.com

SO we need to add the id in android manifest, actually it will not let the app start so we need to see that error in logcat, here is the code to prevent that

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-25144395832518092~33263427654" // your id here
/>
```

You need to add that code in android manifest in application tag

Comment: Come on, this is like pressing every button on keyboard

Comment: HAHAHA, but mostly you will get your problem solved within the first 4 steps.

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov, then also `Reinstall AS, Java`, `Reinstall Windows` and `Update Android`.

Answer (score 0):

in your (AndroidManifest.xml) file don't forget to change 
android.exported='true'
from false to true for the launch activity