# Debug/Run is not working in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever i run or debug application from android studio in any device application installed successfully.

But, application does not launch automatically. I have to manually start application. While debugging application does not launch automatically.So, I can't debug app.

How can i resolve this? Is that any solution for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650116/not-auto-launching-app-when-i-run-thru-android-studio

Comment: Thanks this works...!