# How to disable Instant Run in Android Studio 4.0?

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated to the new Android Studio version 4.0 and there's an irritating issue I am facing which

I believe is a result of instant run (or whatever the new name of this feature is). Basically on using the Android studio run/play button, the app does not launch on the device sometimes and erratically. It always installs but sometimes fails to launch.

I have had similar issues in the past and simply disabled instant run, however, in Android Studio 4.0 I can't see any option anywhere to disable it. I read somewhere that the feature name is changed but searching for that name also didn't yield any results.

How can I disable instant run in android studio 4.0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not Auto launching app when I run thru android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650116/not-auto-launching-app-when-i-run-thru-android-studio)

Comment: No. It happens like once every three builds

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've faced the same issue and disabling parallel run option in the edit configuration window solved the issue for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"Apply Changes" has been introduced in replacement of instant run. Besides the Run green button in Android studio, there is apply change option in android studio 4.