# How can I disable instant run on Android Studio 4?

Tags: android, android-studio

I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62156017/how-to-disable-instant-run-in-android-studio-4-0) but none of the answers actually tell you how to disable it, just give workarounds for the issue. I want to totally disable instant run, how can I do that?

The issue I have is that no matter what I do, use the run button, the debug button, the apply changes button, clean, etc, any code I just wrote won't run until I uninstall the app on the phone, if I don't do that all I see is the old code running. I'm guessing instant run is the issue since I always get the message that says `App restart successful without requiring re-install`.

Answer (score 0):

From android studio 3.5 and above you cant disable it but if your running an earlier version: Go to Android Studio Settings or Preferences (for MAC) -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run. Then deselect the "Enable Instant Run" checkbox at the top.